# Поддомен в denwer

Tags: .htaccess, denwer

Добрый день!
Подскажите решение проблемы в Denwer:
есть основной хост blabla.com, создан поддомен m.blabla.com. Как сделать с помощью htaccess, чтоб при запросе поддомена m.blabla.com открывались фалы с основного домена. Т.е. нужен НЕ редирект на домен, а именно подгрузка файлов с необходимого домена.

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашел:
в файле usr\local\apache\conf\httpd.conf прописать

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  DocumentRoot "Z:/home/blabla.com/www"  
  ServerName "blabla.com"
  ServerAlias "*.blabla.com"
  ScriptAlias /cgi/ "/home/blabla.com/cgi/"
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/home/blabla.com/cgi-bin/"
</VirtualHost>
```

и перезапустить апач